# how to generate correlated random numbers between 0 and 1?

Tags: python

This piece of code generates a random number between the values 0 and 1. How do i change the random number generator that the numbers are still between 0 and 1 but are correlated.

```
loss = 0        
for j in range (0,N): 
    if random.uniform(0,1) < pd_vector[j]: 
         loss=loss+value_vector[j] 
    else: 
        loss=loss+0 #otherwise zero loss   
finalloss[i,0]=loss
```

print(finalloss)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what your code is doing but for a simple correlated set of random numbers you just create a weighting of correlated and uncorrelated side. For example, if you wanted a correlation of 0.6, you can do

```
g = random.uniform(0,1)
correlated_random_number = g*0.6 + random.uniform(0,1)*0.4
```